# How to check if 6 different numbers are already in my lottery database

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to make one more rule, in which it tells me if the 6 numbers of the lottery already came out winner, this code shows how many times a number has come out, but I want one more rule, that if you choose 6 numbers that are already in the database that Say choose another number. I think I can use Json, what do u think?

```
<form method="post" action="verificador.php">
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="text" name="chk1"> 
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="number" name="chk2"> 
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="number" name="chk3"> 
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="number" name="chk4"> 
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="number" name="chk5"> 
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="number" name="chk6"> 
      <input style="width:41px;height:33px;border-radius:50%;" type="number" name="chk7"> 
      <input style="width:20%;height:33px;border-radius:10%" type="submit" name="Chequear" value=Chequear>

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM bolas WHERE bola1='$bola1' or bola2='$bola1'or bola3='$bola1'or bola4='$bola1' or bola5='$bola1'or bola6='$bola1'or bola7='$bola1'";
$sqldos ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS Countdos FROM bolas WHERE bola2='$bola2' or bola1='$bola2' or bola3='$bola2'or bola4='$bola2'or bola5='$bola2' or bola6='$bola2'or bola7='$bola2'";
$sqltres ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counttres FROM bolas WHERE bola3='$bola3'or bola1='$bola3' or bola2='$bola3'or bola4='$bola3'or bola5='$bola3' or bola6='$bola3'or bola7='$bola3'";
$sqlcuatro ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS Countcuatro FROM bolas WHERE bola4='$bola4'or bola1='$bola4' or bola2='$bola4'or bola3='$bola4'or bola5='$bola4' or bola6='$bola4'or bola7='$bola4'";
$sqlcinco ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS Countcinco FROM bolas WHERE bola5='$bola5'or bola1='$bola5' or bola2='$bola5'or bola3='$bola5'or bola4='$bola5' or bola6='$bola5'or bola7='$bola5'";
$sqlseis ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS Countseis FROM bolas WHERE bola6='$bola6'or bola1='$bola6' or bola2='$bola6'or bola3='$bola6'or bola4='$bola6' or bola5='$bola6'or bola7='$bola6'";
$sqlsiete ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS Countsiete FROM bolas WHERE bola7='$bola7'or bola1='$bola7' or bola2='$bola7'or bola3='$bola7'or bola4='$bola7' or bola5='$bola7'or bola6='$bola7'";

$result=$conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$resultdos=$conn->query($sqldos);
$rowdos = $resultdos->fetch_assoc();

$resulttres=$conn->query($sqltres);
$rowtres = $resulttres->fetch_assoc();

$resultcuatro=$conn->query($sqlcuatro);
$rowcuatro = $resultcuatro->fetch_assoc();

$resultcinco=$conn->query($sqlcinco);
$rowcinco = $resultcinco->fetch_assoc();

$resultseis=$conn->query($sqlseis);
$rowseis = $resultseis->fetch_assoc();
```

I hope to use json or mysql query

Comment: From what you wrote, it appears you're unaware what JSON is. Your database is designed badly which makes it impossible to query. Instead of saving numbers as tables AND columns, they should be **rows**. That way you can actually query them and create combinations. This way you made your life harder. It's difficult to help you this way. How would you go about *"using json"* here? What does that even mean to you?

Comment: `I think I can use Json, what do u think?` I'm not sure. Json is a serialization format, useful for sending and receiving data. You can store Json data as well, but I don't think that's a particularly good idea, and I'm not sure it really matters for your final solution..

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink this to one sql:

```
$values = "$bola1,$bola2,$bola3,$bola4,$bola5,$bola6,$bola7";

select count(*) as total from bolas
where bola1 in ($values) and bola2 in ($values)
and bola3 in ($values) and bola4 in ($values)
and bola5 in ($values) and bola6 in ($values) and bola7 in ($values)
```

Comment: thank you man, it worked, in any order it worked, very nice, now you know how I could do "echo" if the 7 numbers were already in the database, how could I put $ row ["total"] in an if else function,for example if the query I get 1 = echo "already those numbers" how i set or  move the $row["total"] as true or false, i kinda know it but if you already had the idea, i will thank you too